# What did I do wrong in my program?

Tags: java

I am writing a program where if someone types in the following two lines:

HELLO, I’D LIKE TO ORDER A FZGH

KID’S MEAL

The program will output it like this:

HELLO, I’D LIKE TO ORDER A KID’S MEAL

In other words, the "FZGH" the user inputs into the sentence will be replaced with the second line's words, as you can see: the "FZGH" is replaced by "KID'S MEAL." Kinda get what I mean? If not, I can elaborate more but this is the best I can explain it as.

I'm really close to solving this! My current output is: HELLO, I’D LIKE TO ORDER A FZGH KID’S MEAL

My program didn't replace the "FZGH" with "KID'S MEAL," and I don't know why that is. I thought that by using the .replaceAll() thingy, it would replace "FZGH" with the "KID'S MEAL," but that didn't really happen. Here is my program so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sentences();
}

public static void sentences() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence1 = console.nextLine();
    String sentence2 = console.nextLine();
    //System.out.println(sentence1 + "\n" + sentence2);
    String word = sentence1.replaceAll("[FZGH]", "");
    word = sentence2;
    System.out.print(sentence1 + word);

}
```

Where did I mess up, resulting in the FZGH still appearing in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sentence1 = sentence1.replaceAll("FZGH", "");
String word = sentence2;
```

Your first (and primary) problem is that you're creating a new `String` named `word`, that you're setting to the value of `sentence1.replaceAll("[FZGH]", "")`. You're then changing the value of `word` to be `sentence2` immediately afterward, so the replacement is lost.

Instead, setting `sentence1` to `sentence1.replaceAll("FZGH", "");` will change `sentence1` to no longer contain the string `"FZGH"`, which is what you're going for. You don't actually need a `word` value at all, so if you'd like to remove it, it wouldn't hurt.

In addition, using `[FZGH]` will replace all `F`'s, `Z`'s, `G`'s, and `H`'s from the string- you should use `FZGH` instead, as this will only remove instances of all four letters in a row.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer now that your problem is solved.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a couple of mistakes. Maybe the following is close...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sentences();
}

public static void sentences() {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence1 = console.nextLine();
    String sentence2 = console.nextLine();
    String sentence3 = sentence1+sentence2;
    String final = sentence3.replaceAll("FZGH", "");
    System.out.print(final);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the string "word"

in place of lines :

```
String word = sentence1.replaceAll("[FZGH]", "");
word = sentence2;
System.out.print(sentence1 + word);
```

use the following lines

```
sentence1 = sentence1.replaceAll("[FZGH]", "");
System.out.print(sentence1 + sentence2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually replace method return a string that should be assign again to sentence1. you can run this code its works fine.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            sentences();
        }

```
public static void sentences() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence1 = "HELLO, I’D LIKE TO ORDER A FZGH";
        String sentence2 = "KID’S MEAL";
        //System.out.println(sentence1 + "\n" + sentence2);
         sentence1 = sentence1.replace("FZGH", "");
       String word = sentence2;
        System.out.print(sentence1 + word);

    }
```